# Issues with saving data from inputs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have to get data from all inputs using `<button onClick={save}>Save All data</button>`. 
The idea of the app is next, the user set a number from input, for example 2, after that appears 2 blocks where he can add how many field he wants in each block. After user submitted all fields with data, he click on `save all data` button, but,now when he is clicking on that button, he get just the data from the `2` block, but i want to get data from all of the blocks and to get something like this after submitting:

```css
   `[
{
    nr: 1
    data: [
        {
            first: "asd",
            last: "asd",
            age: 55,
        },
        {
            first: "adsd",
            last: "s",
            age: 55,
        }
    ]
}

{
    nr: 2,
    data: [
        {
            first: "asd",
            last: "asd",
            age: 5,
        },
        {
            first: "asd",
            last: "asd",
            age: 5,
        }
    ]
}
];`
```

DEMO:https://codesandbox.io/s/mutable-tree-5c1y1?file=/Test.js
**Question**: Why i can't get all data, but just the last?
**Question**: How to achieve what i described avove?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you cannot get all of the data is that you are mapping "nr" array as you can see down below and reassigning "myRef" with each iteration, which means that myRef will only store the last form of the array since it gets overwritten all the time.
For example:

---

i = 0: myRef holds the form with nr={0}
             i = 1: myRef holds the form with nr={1}
             ...

---

```
    {
        nr.map(i => (
            <div>
              <p key={i}>{i}</p>
              <Demo nr={i} myRef={myRef} />
            </div>
        ))
    }
```

What I would suggest is that you could use the Form.Provider feature of antd which is a linkage between multiple forms where you can connect the data you have collected, or use a different "myRef" approach where "myRef" is an array of references that exists on the DOM.

---

Edit

---

What I was talking about by holding a reference to each and every form was something like this:

```
const Nr = () => {
  const [refs, setRefs] = useState([]);

  function changeNr(value) {    
    const formRefs = [...refs];

    while (value > formRefs.length) {
      formRefs.push(createRef());
    }

    while(value < formRefs.length) {
      formRefs.pop();
    }

    setRefs(formRefs);
  }

  function submit() {

  function submit() {
      const result = [];

      for(let i = 0; i < refs.length; i++) {
        result[i] = {
          nr: i,
          data:  refs[i].current.getFieldValue("users")
          }
      }
  }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <InputNumber min={1} max={5} onChange={changeNr} />;
          {refs.map((ref, index) => (
            <div>    
              <Inner setRef={(ref) => refs[index].current = ref} index={index} />
            </div>
          ))}

      <Button type="primary" onClick={() => {submit()}}>
        Submit
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

And in the inner:

```
const Demo = ({ index, setRef }) => {
  const [age, setAge] = useState(null);
  const [form] = Form.useForm();

  useEffect(() => {
    setRef(form);
  }, []);

  function setAgeForAllForms(value) {
    let users = form.getFieldValue("users");

    if (users) {
      users = [...users];
      for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        if (!users[i]) {
          users[i] = {};
        }

        users[i].age = value;
      }
    }

    form.setFieldsValue({"users": users});

    setAge(value);
  }

  return (
    <Form name={index} key={index} autoComplete="off" form={form}>
      <Form.List name={"users"}>
        {(fields, { add, remove }) => {
          return (
            <div>
              <InputNumber
                placeholder="Age"
                onChange={value => setAgeForAllForms(value)}
              />
              {fields.map(field => {
                return (
                  <Space
                    key={field.key}
                    style={{ display: "flex", marginBottom: 8 }}
                    align="start"
                  >
                    <Form.Item
                      {...field}
                      name={[field.name, "first"]}
                      fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "first"]}
                      rules={[
                        { required: true, message: "Missing first name" }
                      ]}
                    >
                      <Input placeholder="First Name" />
                    </Form.Item>
                    <Form.Item
                      {...field}
                      name={[field.name, "last"]}
                      fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "last"]}
                      rules={[{ required: true, message: "Missing last name" }]}
                    >
                      <Input placeholder="Last Name" />
                    </Form.Item>

                    <Form.Item
                      {...field}
                      name={[field.name, "age"]}
                      fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "age"]}
                    >
                      <Input placeholder={"Age"} disabled value={null} />
                    </Form.Item>
                    <MinusCircleOutlined
                      onClick={() => {
                        remove(field.name);
                      }}
                    />
                  </Space>
                );
              })}

              <Form.Item>
                <Button
                  type="dashed"
                  onClick={() => {
                    add({age: age});
                  }}
                  block
                >
                  <PlusOutlined /> Add field
                </Button>
              </Form.Item>
            </div>
          );
        }}
      </Form.List>
    </Form>
  );
};
```

I am creating a new reference for every form you have, and when the `Submit` button is clicked, iterating and getting the value of the `users` in every one of them.

Comment: `use a different "myRef" approach where "myRef" is an array of references that exists on the DOM.`, what do you mean?

Comment: @AshikPaul, could youl take a lok to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62297731/form-provider-does-not-work-properly-saving-data

Comment: now if i add `2` in input number, and i fill booth boxes, i don't get  an entire array of data, but i get 2 separate arrays, how to fix this?

Comment: You can merge the collected data from all of the forms like in the edited answer.

Comment: sorry to bother you, i need last feature and after that i will accept the answer. I added `<InputNumber placeholder="Age" />` and i want for every field from first box, if i wwill add `age 55`, to get for all items this age, and if for the second box i will add `age 5`, to get for all items from that box age: 5. A idded the updated array in the question. It should look like that. Could you help please?  https://codesandbox.io/s/mutable-tree-5c1y1?file=/Inner.js:561-594

Comment: Its is okay, this was something quite tricky to handle in hooks. Ant design seems to have an issue of updating the List items using hooks when the state is updated. I provided a workaround for the issue, and will edit the answer soon.

Comment: could you take a look, please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62624845/nested-forms-in-antdesign

Comment: could you take a look to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62758225/toggle-components-using-reactjs  . Will be great if you will help me.