# Form.Provider does not work properly saving data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I use in my react application Form.Provider from Ant Design library.I use it, because i generate inner forms inside main form. My target is, when i will click on `SUBMIT` button, to output in the same time data from outer form and from inner forms. The number of inner forms depend by user, so  he can generate as many he wants.
My outer form:

```js
<Form.Provider
        onFormFinish={(name, { values, forms }) => {
          console.log(forms);
          if (name === "inner") {
            const { inner } = forms;
            const innerF = inner.getFieldValue("first") || [];
            console.log(innerF);
          }
        }}
      >
        <Form name="outter" onFinish={onFinish}>
          {nr.map(i => (
            <div>
              <p key={i}>{i}</p>
              <Inner nr={i} />
            </div>
          ))}
          <Form.Item name="nr" label="Nr">
            <InputNumber min={1} max={5} onChange={handleInputChange} />;
          </Form.Item>
          <Form.Item>
            <Button htmlType="submit" type="primary">
              Submit
            </Button>
          </Form.Item>
        </Form>
      </Form.Provider>
```

And my inner form

```js
 <Form name="inner" onFinish={onFinish} autoComplete="off">
      <Form.List name="users">
        {(fields, { add, remove }) => {
          return (
            <div>
              {fields.map(field => (
                <Space
                  key={field.key}
                  style={{ display: "flex", marginBottom: 8 }}
                  align="start"
                >
                  <Form.Item
                    {...field}
                    name={[field.name, "first"]}
                    fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "first"]}
                    rules={[{ required: true, message: "Missing first name" }]}
                  >
                    <Input placeholder="First Name" />
                  </Form.Item>
                  <Form.Item
                    {...field}
                    name={[field.name, "last"]}
                    fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "last"]}
                    rules={[{ required: true, message: "Missing last name" }]}
                  >
                    <Input placeholder="Last Name" />
                  </Form.Item>

                  <MinusCircleOutlined
                    onClick={() => {
                      remove(field.name);
                    }}
                  />
                </Space>
              ))}

              <Form.Item>
                <Button
                  type="dashed"
                  onClick={() => {
                    add();
                  }}
                  block
                >
                  <PlusOutlined /> Add field
                </Button>
              </Form.Item>
            </div>
          );
        }}
      </Form.List>

      <Form.Item>
        <Button ref={myRef} type="primary" htmlType="submit">
          -
        </Button>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
```

I added Form.Provider in outer form but i can't figure out how to get all values from inner form and from outer form in the same thime, clicking on `SUBMIT` button.

 Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/mutable-tree-5c1y1?file=/Outer.js:485-1291
Question: Why  Form.Provider does not work and how to output all data, from inner, and from outer form, clicking on the `SUBMIT` button?

Comment: @vjr12, could you take a look please?

Comment: @vjr12, could you take a look? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62709190/save-values-in-a-form-in-reactjs

Answer (score 1):

From what I can understand after reading a little bit of the documentation of Ant Design, in order for the outer `onFinish` to run, one of the forms need to submit. This can either be achieved by holding the reference of the form from the outer component and calling `submit()`, or declaring the button as a children of the `Form.Item`. In the second case, you would get a button after every form. Which is something you don't want. I would say go for the solution I have provided in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62294045/13715293) after the "Edit" part.

Comment: could you take a look, please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62640163/save-data-from-many-forms-using-getfieldvalue

Comment: could you take a look? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62788430/can-not-read-property-0-of-undefined-in-reactjs