# save data from many forms using getFieldValue()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try to save data from 2 form (`Main` and `SubForm`) using `getFieldValue()`. Here should appear both form data:

```js
const save = () => {
    console.log(myRef.current.getFieldValue());
};
```

Now i  get an empty object when i click `save` handler. If i remove the `<SubForm/>` i get value from Main form, but if i add again the second form i ca not get data from both form.
,br> How to get data, clicking on save button, from both forms using `getFieldValue()`?
demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-ganguly-vz7o7?file=/src/OuterForm.js

A part of my code:

```js
     <Form
        name="main"
        ref={myRef}
        initialValues={{ remember: true }}
        onFinish={onFinish}
        onFinishFailed={onFinishFailed}
        id="ma"
        form={form}
      >
        <Form.Item
          label="Username"
          name="username"
          rules={[{ required: true, message: "Please input your username!" }]}
        >
          <Input />
        </Form.Item>

        <Form.Item
          label="Password"
          name="password"
          rules={[{ required: true, message: "Please input your password!" }]}
        >
          <Input.Password />
        </Form.Item>
      </Form>
      <SubForm myRef={myRef} />
      <button onClick={save}>save</button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define 2 refs, one for each form.

```
const mainFormRef = useRef();
const subFormRef = useRef();
```

and set these refs on respective forms

```
<Form
  name="main"
  ref={mainFormRef}
  ....
>
  ....
</Form>

<SubForm myRef={subFormRef} />
```

finally, inside `save` function, call `getFieldValue` on both refs

```
const save = () => {
    console.log(mainFormRef.current.getFieldValue());
    console.log(subFormRef.current.getFieldValue());
};
```

Comment: could you take a look please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62651715/date-picker-does-not-set-date-and-time-correctly