# Date picker does not set date and time correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an application what should take data from a data picker and  from a time picker, and to output this data in console.

```js
function onChange(value, dateString) {
  console.log("Selected Time: ", value);
  console.log("Formatted Selected Time: ", dateString);
}

function onOk(value) {
  console.log("onOk: ", value);
}
function onChangeTime(value) {
  console.log(value);
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <>
    <DatePicker
      renderExtraFooter={() => (
        <RangePicker onChange={onChangeTime} format="HH:mm" />
      )}
      onChange={onChange}
      onOk={onOk}
    />
  </>,
  document.getElementById("container")
);
```

So, inside date picker, on the footer, i have a range time picker what should output value as a range (ex: 10:00 - 12:00). 
**Issue**: Now i have an issue when i try to set a date. When i click on a date, the date picker is closing, and the same issue when i set firstly time, when i click on the second time, the date picker also is closing and i can not manage to set date.
**Question**: How to solve the issue and how to output date in `onChange` function and time in `onChangeTime` function?
demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-wu-roqvr?file=/index.js:206-214

Comment: Don't think you will be able to use `RangePicker` as a footer of `DatePicker` because clicking ok button will close the picker. You can put `RangePicker` and `DatePicker` components next to each other. [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-breeze-wztlv?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 0):

There was a similar issue/ticket posted on the github ant-design bug tracker. For your reference here is a link:

[RangePicker with Select component in renderExtraFooter trigger onOpenChange from RangePicker #24696](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/24696)

There is one way around it, which is to create a controlled date component. Currently what happens is when you select a date in the DatePicker it's default behaviour is to close, the same will occur when the focus is moved away from the DatePicker, i.e. when you interact with the TimePicker.

I suggest the following:

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { DatePicker, TimePicker, Button } from "antd";

const { RangePicker } = TimePicker;

const App = () => {
const [datePickerOpen, setDatePickerOpen] = useState(false);

function onChange(value, dateString) {
   console.log("Selected Time: ", value);
   console.log("Formatted Selected Time: ", dateString);
}

function onOk(value) {
   console.log("onOk: ", value);
}

function onChangeTime(value) {
   console.log(value);
}

return <DatePicker
         open={datePickerOpen}
         onClick={() => setDatePickerOpen(true)} 
         renderExtraFooter={(mode) => <div>
            <RangePicker onChange={onChangeTime} format="HH:mm" />
            <Button onClick={() => setDatePickerOpen(false)}>Apply</Button> 
           </div>
         }
         onChange={onChange}
        />
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <>
    <App/>
  </>,
  document.getElementById("container")
);
```

The main changes to your code is moving the functions into a functional component, add a state hook => [datePickerOpen, setDatePickerOpen] with an initial default value of false. Inside the DatePicker component, I used the "open" attribute to make it a controlled component, and then added an "onClick" event handler to open the DatePicker. Inside the "renderExtraFooter" I added a "div" that acts as a wrapper to the RangePicker and Button components. When the user is finished entering the Date and Time, they can click on the Button "Apply" component to close the DatePicker.

I did not do anything with the styling, and the button is just the default from Ant Design. You can add coloring to bring the attention of the user "Call to Action" on the button, and also apply styling to align the TimePicker and Button.

Hope this helps.