# Save values in a form in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have an application where user can submit data using a form. I'm using dynamic form where user can set how many forms he wants.

```js
 <Form name="dynamic_form_nest_item" onFinish={onFinish} autoComplete="off">
      <Form.List name="users">
        {(fields, { add, remove }) => {
          return (
            <div>
              {fields.map((field, index) =>
                !fieldsOnEdit.includes(index) ? (
                  <Space
                    key={field.key}
                    style={{ display: "flex", marginBottom: 8 }}
                    align="start"
                  >
                    <Form.Item
                      {...field}
                      name={[field.name, "first"]}
                      fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "first"]}
                      rules={[
                        { required: true, message: "Missing first name" }
                      ]}
                    >
                      <Input placeholder="First Name" />
                    </Form.Item>
                    <Form.Item>
                      <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
                        Submit{setFieldOnEdit(index)}
                      </Button>
                    </Form.Item>
                  </Space>
                ) : (
                  <Edit value={formVal} keyForm={index} />
                )
              )}

              <Form.Item>
                <Button
                  type="dashed"
                  onClick={() => {
                    add();
                  }}
                  block
                >
                  <PlusOutlined /> Add field
                </Button>
              </Form.Item>
            </div>
          );
        }}
      </Form.List>
    </Form>
```

When i click on submit button appears `<Edit value={formVal} keyForm={index} />` component where should appears corresponding value from the form. Now there is an issue:
when i save  for example 2 forms, the second value overrides previous and so on.
I made this: `value.users[value.users.length - 1].first`, trying to set for every form corresponding value but it does not work.

Question: How to solve the issue, and when i will save a form to display the corresponding value in  component?

 demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-austin-kqztw?file=/index.js:698-2310

Answer (score 1):

The value is not overwritten, you are rendering always the same item.
You have the index of wanted item in `keyFrom` prop in your `Edit` component, just use it:

```js
export const Edit = ({ value, keyForm }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      edit mode
      <p>value: {value.users[keyForm].first}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: @Iavor, could you take a look, please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62758225/toggle-components-using-reactjs