# Create nested form using react js

Tags: reactjs, antd

I use ant design in my application, where i use dynamic form.  Users can add how many descendant forms they want.

```js
 <Form
      name="dynamic_form_item"
      {...formItemLayoutWithOutLabel}
      onFinish={onFinish}
    >
      <Form.List name="names">
        {(fields, { add, remove }) => {
          return (
            <div>
              {fields.map((field, index) => (
                <Form.Item
                  {...(index === 0
                    ? formItemLayout
                    : formItemLayoutWithOutLabel)}
                  label={index === 0 ? "Passengers" : ""}
                  required={false}
                  key={field.key}
                >
                  <Form.Item
                    {...field}
                    validateTrigger={["onChange", "onBlur"]}
                    rules={[
                      {
                        required: true,
                        whitespace: true,
                        message:
                          "Please input passenger's name or delete this field."
                      }
                    ]}
                    noStyle
                  >
                    <Input
                      placeholder="passenger name"
                      style={{ width: "60%" }}
                    />
                  </Form.Item>
                  <InnerForm />  //my inner form
                  {fields.length > 1 ? (
                    <MinusCircleOutlined
                      className="dynamic-delete-button"
                      style={{ margin: "0 8px" }}
                      onClick={() => {
                        remove(field.name);
                      }}
                    />
                  ) : null}
                </Form.Item>
              ))}
              <Form.Item>
                <Button
                  type="dashed"
                  onClick={() => {
                    add();
                  }}
                  style={{ width: "60%" }}
                >
                  <PlusOutlined /> Add field
                </Button>
              </Form.Item>
            </div>
          );
        }}
      </Form.List>

      <Form.Item>
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
```

The idea of the application is next:
User click on `add field` and appears an input where he can add a value, also appears another button with `add inner field` where user also can add another data.
Now the application works and when i save each form, i get the value, but also i get a warning: `validateDOMNesting(...): <form> cannot appear as a descendant of <form>`, which means that i can't use inner form inside the main how i understand. But how to solve this issue and to make disappears the warning?

 demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-paper-0933k?file=/index.js:677-2823

Comment: so the user can submit individual form or they have to submit all the data at once?

Comment: @Naresh, good point, the user have to submit all data at once, clicking on submit from main form. Do you have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: you are adding a Form inside a Form which is not a good approach. You should add form elements inside a form. Try removing the `Form` from `SubForm.js`

Comment: Also remove the `submit inner` button which doesn't make sense if you want to submit all your data at once.

Comment: @Naresh, i removed the <form> tag from inner form, but now if i want to write something inside inner form, for example i write something in the first input from inner form  and after that in the second input from inner form, the previous values is removing. How to solve this?  https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-paper-0933k?file=/SubForm.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SubForm.js`. Removing the `form` tag gets rid of the warning. and also remove the inner `submit button`

```
import React from "react";

import { Form, Input, Button } from "antd";
import { PlusOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";

const SubForm = props => {
  return (
    <>
      <Form.List name={[props.fieldKey, "inner"]}>
        {(fields, { add, remove }) => {
          return (
            <div>
              {fields.map((field, index) => (
                <Form.Item
                  // name={"aar"}
                  {...field}
                  name={[field.name, "innerName"]}
                  fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "innerName"]}
                  key={index}
                  noStyle
                >
                  <Input
                    placeholder="passenger name"
                    style={{ width: "60%" }}
                  />
                </Form.Item>
              ))}
              <Form.Item>
                <Button
                  type="dashed"
                  onClick={() => {
                    add();
                  }}
                  style={{ width: "60%" }}
                >
                  <PlusOutlined /> Add field
                </Button>
              </Form.Item>
            </div>
          );
        }}
      </Form.List>
    </>
  );
};

export default SubForm;
```

`index.js`

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Form, Input, Button } from "antd";
import { MinusCircleOutlined, PlusOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";
import InnerForm from "./SubForm";

const formItemLayout = {
  labelCol: {
    xs: { span: 24 },
    sm: { span: 4 }
  },
  wrapperCol: {
    xs: { span: 24 },
    sm: { span: 20 }`
  }
};`
const formItemLayoutWithOutLabel = {
  wrapperCol: {
    xs: { span: 24, offset: 0 },
    sm: { span: 20, offset: 4 }
  }
};

const DynamicFieldSet = () => {
  const onFinish = values => {
    console.log("Received values of form:", values);
  };

  return (
    <Form
      name="dynamic_form_item"
      {...formItemLayoutWithOutLabel}
      onFinish={onFinish}
    >
      <Form.List name="names">
        {(fields, { add, remove }) => {
          return (
            <div>
              {fields.map((field, index) => {
                console.log(field);
                return (
                  <Form.Item
                    {...(index === 0
                      ? formItemLayout
                      : formItemLayoutWithOutLabel)}
                    label={index === 0 ? "Passengers" : ""}
                    required={false}
                    key={field.key}
                  >
                    <Form.Item
                      {...field}
                      name={[field.name, "outer"]}
                      fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "outer"]}
                      validateTrigger={["onChange", "onBlur"]}
                      rules={[
                        {
                          required: true,
                          whitespace: true,
                          message:
                            "Please input passenger's"
                        }
                      ]}
                      noStyle
                    >
                      <Input
                        placeholder="passenger name"
                        style={{ width: "60%" }}
                      />
                    </Form.Item>
                    <Form.Item>
                      <InnerForm fieldKey={field.key} />
                    </Form.Item>
                    {fields.length > 1 ? (
                      <MinusCircleOutlined
                        className="dynamic-delete-button"
                        style={{ margin: "0 8px" }}
                        onClick={() => {
                          remove(field.name);
                        }}
                      />
                    ) : null}
                  </Form.Item>
                );
              })}
              <Form.Item>
                <Button
                  type="dashed"
                  onClick={() => {
                    add();
                  }}
                  style={{ width: "60%" }}
                >
                  <PlusOutlined /> Add field
                </Button>
              </Form.Item>
            </div>
          );
        }}
      </Form.List>

      <Form.Item>
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<DynamicFieldSet />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Comment: when i try to add data in subform fields the value from previous input from subform disappears. Do you now a solution? https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-paper-0933k?file=/SubForm.js

Comment: @Asking I've updated the answer. It should be working . also here is the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-lovelace-f7eso)

Comment: it works great, but there is a warning: `Encountered two children with the same key, `1`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates`. Do you now why the issue appears?

Comment: I don't see any warnings. can you refresh the code sandbox and try again?

Comment: thanks. Could you take a look for a moment and here. Thanks a lot https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62709190/save-values-in-a-form-in-reactjs

Comment: @Naresh, could you take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62758225/toggle-components-using-reactjs

Comment: @Naresh, could you take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62758225/toggle-components-using-reactjs . It will be great if you will help. Thanks

Comment: @Naresh, could you help with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65574664/cant-download-a-file-in-reactjs

Comment: @Naresh, could you help please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67882888/group-inputs-in-react-js