# Toggle components using reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an application where user could add data inside form and after that he can save it and get the values. Also, i have a dynamic form `<DynamicFieldSet/>` where user can add how many fields he wants.
In dynamic form i have to switch between each form. The component that should be switched `<Edit/>`. So when user clicks on `submit` button, should appears `<Edit/>` component, and when the component will appear, user can switch back clicking on `back to default mode` button.

 **Scenario**: User clicks on `Add field`, after that on `Add field to inner`, and fill the input. After that clicks on `submit inner` button, after that should appear `<Edit/>` component with the data from input. When user click on `back to default mode`, should appear default mode.

```
     <Form.List onFinish={onFinish} name={[props.fieldKey, "inner"]}>
          {(fields, { add, remove }) => {
            return (
              <div>
                {fields.map((field, index) =>
                  !fieldsOnEdit.includes(index) && defaultMode === true ? (
                    <Space
                      key={field.key}
                      style={{ display: "flex", marginBottom: 8 }}
                      align="start"
                    >
                      <Form.Item
                        {...field}
                        name={[field.name, "first"]}
                        fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "first"]}
                        rules={[{ required: true, message: "Missing first name" }]}
                      >
                        <Input placeholder="First Name" />
                      </Form.Item>
                      <Form.Item>
                        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
                          Submit inner{setFieldOnEdit(index)}
                        </Button>
                      </Form.Item>
                    </Space>
                  ) : (
                    <Edit value={formVal} mode={setDefaultMode} keyForm={index} />
                  )
                )}

                <Form.Item>
                  <Button
                    type="dashed"
                    onClick={() => {
                      add();
                    }}
                    block
                  >
                    <PlusOutlined /> Add field to inner
                  </Button>
                </Form.Item>
              </div>
            );
          }}
        </Form.List>
```

**Question: How to achieve what i described?**

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-ives-o81ue?file=/SubForm.js

Comment: Try to specify where exactly you have a problem in your current implementation. And what is not working as you would expected.

Comment: @lavor, my problem is when i click `submit inner` button. Clicking on it should appear `<Edit/>` component instead of input with `first name` placeholder. Now i can't figure out how to do this in my example. Also, when will appear `Edit/>` component and when user will click on `back to default mode` button, instead of `<Edit/>` component should appear the input back. Could you help?

Answer (score 0):

There is a very straightforrward solution for this, I suggest you to learn how to debug an application properly to find out what the problem your code have. And only when you cannot figure how to solve the problem after proper debugging, start asking others here on stackoverflow.

---

So the solution.

You are displaying `Edit` component when `fieldsOnEdit` contains the index OR `defaultMode` is false.
So when you are entering edit mode, you've put index into your `fieldsOnEdit` and set `defaultMode` to false. That's correct.
But when your are leaving edit mode you are setting `defaultMode` to true, but you did not remove its index from `fieldsOnEdit`.

So you need to do both, create new callback:

```js
const setBackToDefaultMode = index => {
    // remove index from array
    setFieldsOnEdit(prevIndexes => prevIndexes.filter(item => item !== index));
    // set default mode
    setDefaultMode(true);
  };
```

Pass this new callback to `Edit` props:

```js
<Edit
    value={props.values}
    mode={setBackToDefaultMode}
    keyForm={index}
/>
```

Comment: @Iavor, i changed, but i get `Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate.`, could you add in codesanbox? thanks

Comment: @Iavor, i changed sanbox, it works, but just for first input. If i add text in first form and click on `submit inner` button and after that click on `Add field to inner`, i get `Cannot read property 'first' of undefined`, also if i click on `back to default mode`, saw that each field are back to default mode, but i want just to back just that field where i click. Please let me know if i explained clear. Thanks

Comment: @Iavor, what do you think about the issue?

Comment: @AskMen As I wrote above, try to fix it yourself first. In your code there are multiple issue, I cannot solve everything for you.

Comment: @Iavor, I fixed a part of my issue, but i want to ask you to help me in the next situation: when i will click on back to default mode to toggle just the component that i clicked not all components. The same issue is if i fill many inputs and after that i try to submit, in this case all forms will be toggled but i want to togle just that form that was submited. Please, tell me if the issue is clear. The sanbox is updated

Comment: @Iavor, could you take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62871247/increase-the-next-value-by-a-certain-number-in-relation-to-the-first-value?noredirect=1#comment111179577_62871247

Comment: @lavor, could you take a look, please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63377199/add-data-in-a-specific-proprety-of-object